# how to solve react js installation problem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
PS D:\React-project> node --version
v15.11.0
PS D:\React-project> npm --version
7.6.1
PS D:\React-project> npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\FAZAL JALIL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-07T03_36_15_134Z-debug.log
npm ERR! errno ENOTDIR
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app: ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir 'C:\Users\FAZAL JALIL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-07T03_36_15_134Z-debug.log'
PS D:\React-project>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ENOTDIR` refers to the error where `npm` can't find the designated directory.

Try to clean the cache, that should do it.

`npm cache clean --force` (`--force` is must parameter)